# how to update table by copying data from colum a b c to colum d in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a long list of data and i would want to copy data from three columns and combine them in one column as in the image below

[image: image of database]

So that the result would be like in the table below: 
Any answer mysql  would be highly appreciated

i.e. `UPDATE location SET ...` something like that

[image]

Comment: just out of curiosity - why do you want to do that? The data duplication contradicts Normal Forms

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I wanted to create more tags on the `more` column and add more tags on top of that,  i also wanted to export that column alone while containing the whole location tags and use it somewhere else. The list was very long too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following query:

**Query#1**

```
UPDATE location SET more = CONCAT(county,' ',constituency,' ',ward);
```

---

**Note:**

If `county` OR `constituency` OR `ward` column contains NULL THEN you may check null before updating:

**Query#2**

```
UPDATE location
SET more = CONCAT( IFNULL(county, ''),' ',IFNULL(constituency, ''),' ',IFNULL(ward,''));
```

---

**Why should you go for `Query#2`**

---

You may get an idea about the reason behind using `IFNULL`:

`SELECT CONCAT('ABCD',null,'EFGH');`

**Result:** **`NULL`**

`SELECT CONCAT('ABCD',IFNULL(null,''),'EFGH')`

**Result:** **`ABCDEFGH`**

---

**Caution:**

`CONCAT_WS` might encounter data loss. The following example is a good indication:

`SELECT CONCAT_WS('ABCD',null,'EFGH')`

**Result:** `EFGH`. (You just lost `ABCD`)

Comment: Thank you it worked great. What happens if some have NULL?

Comment: Please check the updated query and the sample example indicating the use of `IFNULL` @OmariOmosa

Comment: You definitely go for the second query. Otherwise data loss might occur. @OmariOmosa

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
UPDATE location SET more = CONCAT_WS(' ',county,constituency,ward);
```

Comment: CONCAT_WS to ignore NULL is nice and clean

Comment: Great you helped me alot,

Comment: `CONCAT_WS` might encounter data loss. Please check this example: `SELECT CONCAT_WS('ABCD',null,'EFGH')` RETRUNS **EFGH**. Where's **ABCD**? @OmariOmosa @Taff

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONACT()` method of mysql like this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET d = CONCAT CONCAT(a ,' ' ,b ,' ' ,c);
```